# Data mapper pattern for API data instead of Database

Tags: php, laravel

I am using API data intensively in my projects (PHP Laravel projects). All my data source comes from different API calls instead of database. I feel bad because Laravel's Eloquent ORM is so handy to use however I couldn't use them at all.

I am just wondering if there is a php package which converts the api call data (Multidimensional array) to a PHP class object automatically.

For example, by having the following array:

```
[id:1, name:'Foo', children: [[id: 5, color: 'green'], [id: 5, color: 'red']]]
```

be converted to:

```
Class Product {
   protected $id;
   protected $name;
   protected $children;
}
```

I guess it probably needs some sort of YML file to indicate the mapping logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Sort of..

You should take a look at the [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Model.html) and [Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection](http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Database.Eloquent.Collection.html) classes. Those implement all the interfaces you're probably looking for, like Jsonable, Arrayable, Countable.

When you request data from the API you can make an instantiation of the model and pass your data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I like this idea.